# update text of textbox on check of checkbox

Tags: javascript, function, checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" id="one" onclick="updatebox()"/>1
<input type="checkbox" id="two" onclick="updatebox()"/>2
<input type="checkbox" id="three" onclick="updatebox()"/>3
<input type="text" id="tbtb"/>
```

I have 3 checkboxes and a textbox. I want that when all checkboxes are checked the textbox value would be like "123" and if one of them is not checked the value should go like "12" or "13" or "23". I dont need comma for this, I just need these to use as conditional values. 
To be specific here I want that they would still be in order though they are not checked consecutively in order. I need the java script function for this

and also when they will be unchecked the textbox should not contain the value they have. like when all are checked then u uncheck #1 the value should be "23". "1" should be removed on the text. coz right now the code i have that:

```
var one = document.getelementbyID('one');
var textbox = document.getelementbyID('tbtb').value;
if (one.checked)
{
textbox = textbox + "1";
}
```

so what's happening here is everytime a checkbox is checked and unchecked simultaneously the value of textbox keep adding another "1" it goes like "2311111". PLEASE HELP :)

Comment: It's `getElementById` not `getelementbyID`, case matters

Comment: Do u plan to use jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```js
var one = document.getElementById('one');
var two = document.getElementById('two');
var three = document.getElementById('three');
var textbox = document.getElementById('tbtb');

function updatebox(){
    var str = "";
    if(one.checked)
      str+="1";
  if(two.checked)
      str+="2";
  if(three.checked)
      str+="3";
  textbox.value = str;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="chk" id="one" onclick="updatebox()"/>1
<input type="checkbox" class="chk" id="two" onclick="updatebox()"/>2
<input type="checkbox" class="chk" id="three" onclick="updatebox()"/>3
<input type="text" id="tbtb"/>
```

Comment: You can not use ID in this way.What if there is N number  of checkboxes?Are you going to define and take each check-box individually?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
    function updatebox()
    {
    var textbox = $('#tbtb').val();;


    if($('#one').prop('checked')) {
        $("#tbtb").val(textbox + "1");
    }

    if($('#two').prop('checked')) {
        $("#tbtb").val(textbox + "1");
    }

    if($('#three').prop('checked')) {
        $("#tbtb").val(textbox + "1");
    }

    }
```

and HTML part is:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="one" onclick="updatebox()"/>1
<input type="checkbox" id="two" onclick="updatebox()"/>2
<input type="checkbox" id="three" onclick="updatebox()"/>3
<input type="text" id="tbtb"/>
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

JS:

```
function updatebox() {

    var arrCheckbox = document.querySelectorAll('input[name=common-check]:checked');

     var textBox = document.getElementById("tbtb");
     var strCheck = "";
     for(var i=0;i < arrCheckbox.length;i++){

        strCheck+=arrCheckbox[i].getAttribute('check');
     }
     textBox.value = strCheck
  }
```

HTML :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="common-check" id="one" onclick="updatebox()" check="1"/>1
<input type="checkbox" name="common-check" id="two" onclick="updatebox()"  check="2"/>2
<input type="checkbox" name="common-check" id="three" onclick="updatebox()" check="3"/>3
<input type="text" id="tbtb"/>
```

Here is the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZmMRZpkNGHaTLRJPYAX3?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

try this

**javascript**

```
function updatebox()
    {
        var one = document.getElementById('one');
        var two = document.getElementById('two');
        var three = document.getElementById('three');
        var textbox = document.getElementById('tbtb');

            var str = "";
            if(one.checked)
                str+=one.value;
            if(two.checked)
                str+=two.value;
            if(three.checked)
                str+=three.value;
          textbox.value = str;
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox"  value="1" id="one" onclick="updatebox()"/>1
<input type="checkbox" value="2" id="two" onclick="updatebox()"/>2
<input type="checkbox" value="3" id="three" onclick="updatebox()"/>3
<input type="text" id="tbtb"/>
```